# How to convert decimal types?

Tags: c#, .net, types

So i have a problem with decimal type .
My task :
Description
There are a point and a line in 3D space. Find the distance between them.
Input:

Nine reals, the 3D coordinates of:

1. ```
    The given point.
   ```
2. ```
    The point on the line.
   ```
3. ```
    The direction vector of the line.
   ```

The length of the direction vector is greater than 1e-8.
Output:
A real, the distance between the given point and the line.
Example:

Input:
1.0 1.0 1.0 2.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0
Output:
1.0
My code:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var input = Console.ReadLine();
    var numbers = input.Split(' ').Select(x => decimal.Parse(x)).ToArray();
    var m0 = new[] {numbers[0],numbers[1],numbers[2] };
    var m1 = new[] { numbers[3], numbers[4], numbers[5] };
    var s= new[] { numbers[6], numbers[7], numbers[8] };
    decimal[] m1m0=new decimal[3];
    for(int i =0;i<3;i++)
    {
        m1m0[i] = m1[i] - m0[i];
    }
    
    decimal[] m1m0s = new decimal[3];
    m1m0s[0] = m1m0[1] * s[2] - m1m0[2] * s[1];
    m1m0s[1] = m1m0[2] * s[0] - m1m0[0] * s[2];
    m1m0s[2] = m1m0[0] * s[1] - m1m0[1] * s[0];
    var d = GetAbs(m1m0s[0], m1m0s[1], m1m0s[2]) / GetAbs(s[0], s[1], s[2]);

    Console.WriteLine((decimal)d);
}
static decimal GetAbs(decimal a , decimal b , decimal c )
{
    var  d = a * a + b * b + c * c;
    double e = (double)d;
    var temp= Math.Sqrt(e);
    decimal sqrt = Convert.ToDecimal(temp);
    return sqrt ;
}
```

My result of program :
input
1.0 1.0 1.0 2.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0
output
1

I need my result to be with a  floating point, even if I get an integer type .Output need to be 1.0 or 2.0 ,but not a 1 or 2 .

Comment: I don't think this is a conversion problem, but a display problem. I would try `Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("0.0"));` if you want it to always display 1 decimal

Comment: @jdweng so its not working

Comment: @Knoop but its round my result , and i dont need it

Comment: Then you want what? More then one decimal place or the value just cut of to one decimal place (so that 1.09 becomes 1.0)?

Comment: @Ralf i just need to output my value in format like this: 1.0 ,2.0 or 1.4343434 or 0.434343

Comment: If you change the first input value to 2.0 the result will be sqrt(2). That's an irrational value (has an infinite number of decimal places). How many do you want to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("0.0#######"));
```

format string `"0.0#######"` cuts all trailing zeroez but guarantees at least one digit after decimal point.

possible input and ouput:

```
Math.Sqrt(2);
1.41421356

Math.Sqrt(0.02); 
0.14142136

Math.Sqrt(1);
1.0

Math.Sqrt(0.0001);
0.01
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want a decimal point only if value is a whole number and preserve the digits if it a fraction do it as below -

```
if (d % 1 == 0)
{
     Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:0.0}", d));
}
else
{
     Console.WriteLine(d);
}
```